# Running ssh-host-config

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I tried to run ssh-host-config after Cygwin installation. It is failing with below error:

```
$ **ssh-host-config**
/usr/bin/ssh-host-config: line 49: /usr/share/csih/cygwin-service-installation-helper.sh: No such file or directory
```

Physically files are available in the path. I verified the PATH variable, it is pointing to D:\cygwin\bin;D:\cygwin\usr\bin.

I also ran the mount command:

```
D:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
D:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)

**> C:/cygwin on /usr type ntfs (binary)**

D:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
```

Highlighted is the wrong mounted path.

**I tried to unmount it and point to proper path but it didn't work**. Actually I was trying Hadoop cluster installation in my machine.

Comment: The error is saying that /usr/share/csih/cygwin-service-installation-helper.sh is missing. This file comes from the "csih" package. Run the Cygwin setup.exe and install this package.

Answer (score 0):

I am installing in Windows XP m/c. 
Instead of cygwin\usr\bin folder cygwin creates cygwin\usr\sbin in my m/c. Hence **sbin** folder should be in the path.

Chec[k](https://sites.google.com/site/learningcomputervision/veer_khari_fraud) if that's the issue with you.
I am following instruction from here:

http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/05%20-%20Setup%20SSHD.html